# Upload csv file using javascript and d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am new to JavaScript and D3 and cannot figure out how to allow users to upload a csv file and displaying a scatterplot using d3. I am using the  tag to allow user to select file. But I am not sure on what the next step should be. Is there a way to read the csv file and store it's contents in a d3 array and then displaying a graph using that array ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `d3.csv` function (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). Here is a simple example

```
//load up the example.csv file
d3.csv('example.csv',
    function(data){
        //this is an object, the contents of which should
        //match your example.csv input file.
        console.log(data);

        // do more stuff with 'data' related to 
        // drawing the scatterplots.
        //
        //-----------------------
    }, 
   function(error, rows) {
       console.log(rows);
   };
);
```

There are a number of examples online showing you how to go from a data array to a scatterplot...it's a matter of modifying those examples to fit your specific data format.

Comment: But how do I upload the file after the user selects it??

Comment: Trying doing a google search on 'uploading csv file javacsript'.

Comment: I have searched a lot but still can't find a way to upload a file, all the examples out there are for importing file during development, not for uploading file from user end. I have got <input type='file' id='file'> <input type='button' id='_submit' value='Upload!'> and stuck there :(

Comment: But the csv file contains just 2 columns with 10 rows max, therefore, I wanted to just store the contents of the file as an array and then d3 could use that array to plot some graphs.